# Duplicated records in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I need to return the ID of the duplicate records from a table using HQL. I Tried:

```
"select pro from FichaProcedimento pro "
                + " inner join ("
                + " select pro.ficha.id, proc.id, proc.regiaoDente, proc.face "
                + " from FichaProcedimento "
                + " group by  pro.ficha.id, proc.id, proc.regiaoDente, proc.face" 
                + " having count(*)>1) proc "
                + " on pro.procedimento.id = proc.procedimento.id "
                + " where pro.ficha.id=? "
```

Error occurred:

> unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 100 [select pro from br.srv.datasolution.infodata.odontologico.entity.FichaProcedimento pro  inner join ( select pro.ficha.id, proc.id, proc.regiaoDente, proc.face  from br.srv.datasolution.infodata.odontologico.entity.FichaProcedimento  group by  pro.ficha.id, proc.id, proc.regiaoDente, proc.face having count(*)>1) proc  on pro.procedimento.id = proc.procedimento.id  where pro.ficha.id=? ]

How to solve?

Comment: Using HQL, you can get FichaProcedimento models not the id's alone. To do that either use criteria query or native sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with native query. Thanks! Example:

```
delete from Tabela
where Nome in
(select Nome from Tabela
group by Nome
having Count(Nome)>1)
and not matricula in
(select Min(Matricula) from Tabela
group by Nome
having Count(Nome)>1)
```